# Prove that differential equations are right continuous with respect to initial values.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Here the question.

Consider the initial value problem:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases} \frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y) \\y(x_0)=y_0,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$f(x,y)$ is continuous. Suppose that $y=\phi(x;x_0,y_0)$ is the maximum solution of the initial value problem. Prove:$\phi(x;x_0,y_0)$ is right continuous for $y$, that is
\begin{equation}
\lim_{y_1\to y_0^+}\phi(x;x_0,y_1)=\phi(x;x_0,y_0)
\end{equation}
establishs on $|x-x_0|\leq \alpha$, $\alpha$ is constant.

Below is my idea.

Consider the equations
\begin{equation}
(*)_n=\begin{cases}\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)+\frac{1}{n}, \\y(x_0)=y_0,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
write the sequence of solutions as $\{\phi_n(x;x_0,y_0)\}$.It has a uniformly convergent subsequence,let itself be uniformly convergent.

Assume that $\phi(x;x_0,y_0)$ is not right continuous for $y_0$, then $\exists \epsilon>0,\forall \delta>0,\exists y_{\delta}-y_0<\delta$, such that  $$|\phi(x;x_0,y_{\delta})-\phi(x;x_0,y_0)|\geq  \epsilon.$$

Let $\{\delta_n\}$ decreases to $0$,The corresponding $y_{\delta}$ is denoted by $y_n$. According to the uniform convergence, $\exists N>0,\forall n>N$, we have
\begin{equation}
|\phi_n(x;x_0,y_0)-\phi(x;x_0,y_0)|<\epsilon.
\end{equation}
Then we can get
\begin{equation}
|\phi(x;x_0,y_{n})-\phi(x;x_0,y_0)|\leq|\phi(x;x_0,y_{n})-\phi_n(x;x_0,y_{0})|+|\phi_n(x;x_0,y_{0})-\phi(x;x_0,y_0)|.
\end{equation}
The latter item can be controlled by $\epsilon$,but I don't know how to handle the previous item.Do you have a good idea? I really appreciate it!

Comment: If you have only continuity of $f$, solutions to IVP might not be unique and you should not get continuity with respect to initial condition.

Comment: The problem is to prove the right continuity of the maximum solution.@ArcticChar

Comment: Are you sure you have only continuity of $f$ as an assumption, but not Lipschitz?

Comment: There seems to be a confusion here with right continuity...confusing one thing for another. There is some continuity of the maximal interval of definition... and it is a half continuity. It has to do with the maximal domain of definition being open. Maybe your question is about this.

Comment: yes,perhaps the maximum solution has better properties.@ArcticChar

Comment: This section is about continuity with respect to initial data and parameters, the question  examines the right continuity of the maximum solution to the initial value.@orangeskid

Comment: By maximum solution you mean a solution where the domain of definition is the largest, right?

Comment: No,it means that the function value of other solutions is smaller than it.@ArcticChar

Answer (score 0):

Now that $\phi(n)$ is uniformly convergent to the $\phi$, what we need to prove is that $\phi(n)$ is continuous, according to the later theorem: the continuity of the solution with respect to the initial value, we can get the $\phi(n)$ is continuous for y.[notice: even the later theorem: the continuity of the solution with respect to the initial value need the Lipschitz condition, you just need the first half of the proof.]

Comment: Which later theorem are you referring to?